# How can I programatically verify a password in newer versions of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, authentication, passwords

In newer versions of MySQL there is a pluggable authentication system. Previously there was the PASSWORD function that could generate the hash found in `user.authentication_string`, but that function has been removed in later versions (8.0.11 AFAICT) of MySQL.

If I would like to verify a users password (without actually logging in - since a user may not be able to log in from the host that I'm on), is there a way to do that using modern MySQL?

Comment: i assume your MySQL 8 server is running on `mysql_native_password` ?

Comment: It might be, but not necessarily. If there's a plugin agnostic way to do this it would be great. If not, I can limit this usage to the `mysql_native_password`

Comment: Check mine answer it think that would help out.

Answer (score 1):

> If I would like to verify a users password (without actually logging
>   in - since a user may not be able to log in from the host that I'm
>   on), is there a way to do that using modern MySQL?

`PASSWORD(..)` function seams to be the same as using this SQL `CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1(..)))))`

I don't know where you use the password for, but you should not use it for your passwords for your application.

> **Note**
>
> `PASSWORD()` is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you
>   should not use it in your own applications. For that purpose, consider
>   a more secure method

**Query**

```
  SELECT
        PASSWORD('password')
      , CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('password'))))) 
      , PASSWORD('password') = CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('password')))));
```

**Result**

```
| PASSWORD('password')                      | CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('password'))))) | PASSWORD('password') = CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('password'))))) |
| ----------------------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19         | 1                                                                        |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hzQTJjMBvdpfpJwz4NM8wp/3)

A better test seams to confirm it.

**Query**

```
SELECT
   HEX(number_generator.number) AS 'password'
 , PASSWORD(HEX(number_generator.number))
 # notice that HEX(number_generator.number) below is the "password" here             
 , CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1( HEX(number_generator.number) ))))) 
 , PASSWORD(HEX(number_generator.number)) = CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1( HEX(number_generator.number) )))))                                  
FROM (                                                                 
  SELECT 
   @row := @row + 1 AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row2
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @row := 0 
  ) init_user_params
) AS number_generator
```

**Results**

```
| password | PASSWORD(HEX(number_generator.number))    | CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1( HEX(number_generator.number) ))))) | PASSWORD(HEX(number_generator.number)) = CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1( HEX(number_generator.number) ))))) |
| -------- | ----------------------------------------- | --------------------------------------------------------------------- | -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 1        | *E6CC90B878B948C35E92B003C792C46C58C4AF40 | *E6CC90B878B948C35E92B003C792C46C58C4AF40                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 2        | *12033B78389744F3F39AC4CE4CCFCAD6960D8EA0 | *12033B78389744F3F39AC4CE4CCFCAD6960D8EA0                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 3        | *C4E74DDDC9CC9E2FDCDB7F63B127FB638831262E | *C4E74DDDC9CC9E2FDCDB7F63B127FB638831262E                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 4        | *908BE2B7EB7D7567F7FF98716850F59BA69AA9DB | *908BE2B7EB7D7567F7FF98716850F59BA69AA9DB                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 5        | *7534F9EAEE5B69A586D1E9C1ACE3E3F9F6FCC446 | *7534F9EAEE5B69A586D1E9C1ACE3E3F9F6FCC446                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 6        | *C3AB9ECDF746570BBF9DCAA9DB3586D25956DC93 | *C3AB9ECDF746570BBF9DCAA9DB3586D25956DC93                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 7        | *23E7A7428138939FBE2F69D23E5B87383EFD83C9 | *23E7A7428138939FBE2F69D23E5B87383EFD83C9                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 8        | *6AF37A8C78E3A957D16D98F12788D1CFB2987A4C | *6AF37A8C78E3A957D16D98F12788D1CFB2987A4C                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 9        | *7E9FDC7F61153649AB9A75CED26807DF74F86E65 | *7E9FDC7F61153649AB9A75CED26807DF74F86E65                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| A        | *26307F6B5CDB40C15C247B96C131CC1E0B3FFD1B | *26307F6B5CDB40C15C247B96C131CC1E0B3FFD1B                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| B        | *693EFD3BD44CCBA9924731C2DB18ADB8825C0B0A | *693EFD3BD44CCBA9924731C2DB18ADB8825C0B0A                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| C        | *8B1F657800F87E02617CD07126FDCF7B9F13E955 | *8B1F657800F87E02617CD07126FDCF7B9F13E955                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| D        | *3F7A80713CAA5954D376F883C83B8E4FEFEAF72C | *3F7A80713CAA5954D376F883C83B8E4FEFEAF72C                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| E        | *1355D7A5CA049A2A7FA92669438A10C77D4FB706 | *1355D7A5CA049A2A7FA92669438A10C77D4FB706                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| F        | *2201A8B92856ABC4CDA3731B6D3AC61EEC87916C | *2201A8B92856ABC4CDA3731B6D3AC61EEC87916C                             | 1                                                                                                              |
...
...                                                                                                           |
...                                                                                                            |
| 53       | *30E6AFC81FB2DB79651D461029189713DDD2D847 | *30E6AFC81FB2DB79651D461029189713DDD2D847                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 54       | *A28085F893F86EA1E692F52D847EA3B203C448E1 | *A28085F893F86EA1E692F52D847EA3B203C448E1                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 55       | *4C951E13CC5E761093F241590580096A2276ECAC | *4C951E13CC5E761093F241590580096A2276ECAC                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 56       | *060C8650684D90D54F2D537D0B8513C74F1AE4DD | *060C8650684D90D54F2D537D0B8513C74F1AE4DD                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 57       | *F22C0306C4BB97CAE897F4BA7A3D22870725E51D | *F22C0306C4BB97CAE897F4BA7A3D22870725E51D                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 58       | *C96B8933A9A02563E00980C026C3401B1E3FB6A2 | *C96B8933A9A02563E00980C026C3401B1E3FB6A2                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 59       | *42AC75307953D669FDEBD5928227A0A991AABFB0 | *42AC75307953D669FDEBD5928227A0A991AABFB0                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 5A       | *A43D92E9EC11516AC82C4561124A08E91DE4F208 | *A43D92E9EC11516AC82C4561124A08E91DE4F208                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 5B       | *0A89BF1EEF0EDB061EE4F72477E498E5C3233909 | *0A89BF1EEF0EDB061EE4F72477E498E5C3233909                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 5C       | *78B1EECD64E0949B20E747230E30538898833DC1 | *78B1EECD64E0949B20E747230E30538898833DC1                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 5D       | *C536CE7F28C05D5BBB5E776A92D9DCFF515A6955 | *C536CE7F28C05D5BBB5E776A92D9DCFF515A6955                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 5E       | *5C1BA2FD08D6FC2724860A81B70B44CC14912E95 | *5C1BA2FD08D6FC2724860A81B70B44CC14912E95                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 5F       | *7031DDE5CFC93067F81FBD30445112136AB32E53 | *7031DDE5CFC93067F81FBD30445112136AB32E53                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 60       | *0B30A071BE5EFE9C738FC899EFF47F90202C533D | *0B30A071BE5EFE9C738FC899EFF47F90202C533D                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 61       | *DCDBF922065A133AE5985C3AA7465179DF4C8086 | *DCDBF922065A133AE5985C3AA7465179DF4C8086                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 62       | *0B3DF0C237D6FD5EA8D743889B33384299F8059F | *0B3DF0C237D6FD5EA8D743889B33384299F8059F                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 63       | *2A3522DE0C5E510153DA977554999B35C2CA0B56 | *2A3522DE0C5E510153DA977554999B35C2CA0B56                             | 1                                                                                                              |
| 64       | *61EB3D64954A1F12CD41EA35F2EB27A0E785E997 | *61EB3D64954A1F12CD41EA35F2EB27A0E785E997                             | 1
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hzQTJjMBvdpfpJwz4NM8wp/8)

Comment: The function [Password()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) was never intended to be used to store user passwords, please follow the link and read the "Note" boxes. Furthermore it will be removed in future versions completely. To store passwords one needs a password-hash function with a cost factor like BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2 or Argon2.

Comment: *"o store passwords one needs a password-hash function with a cost factor like BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2 or Argon2."* @martinstoeckli i know i have no idea where the topicstarter is using this for also there is no server side programming tag, so you should place your comment under his question not this answer or you should atleast have used a ping to redirect your comment to him, i've atleast added the warning in the answer now.

Comment: @WayneWerner see this answers update and these comments.