# Recover the passwords created using PASSWORD() in mysql 8

Tags: mysql, password-hash

I have updated my existing `MySQL 5.7` system into `MySQL 8.0` All passwords are encrypted using MySQL `PASSWORD()` function.

> PASSWORD() function is deprecated in `MySQL 8.0`

How can I recover my old passwords into new system?

Can I restore the old passwords?
Is there a method to convert MYSQL `hash password` into another encryption?

Comment: Well no there is not a native way to get that old password back unless you brute force crack.. As `PASSWORD(..)`  is more or less implemented as `CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1(..)))))` which i explain in mine [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150300/how-can-i-programatically-verify-a-password-in-newer-versions-of-mysql/55150700#55150700) which is hashing which can not be reversed.. But as SHA1 is a fast hashing algortihm it should not take long on modern hardware to bruteforce geuss..  Some GPU cracking software has custom patterns which you can use and do the same with..

Comment: ... But you could try ro modify the SQL code from mine answer if you want to try the brute in SQL where the number_generator alias is used and brute crack your password hash.. But then you need to add (much) more `CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) row<number>` to generate more numbers

Comment: The other SQL then needs to have a `PASSWORD(HEX(number_generator.number)) = CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1( HEX(number_generator.number) ))))) = '<your_hash>'` filter to only select a match.. If not is found add more above to add above to generate more numbers..  But at some time you will run into a limit because of the `HEX()` function usage..

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland. I'm get this work with `CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1(pwd)))))`

Comment: Why do you want to "restore" passwords? That's not how passwords work

Comment: Need to work all login accounts to be work. Tried to convert the encryption method. But able to do the same thing manually without using `password()` function

Comment: Sathiska, keep in mind you should not use this method for (desktop/web) applications user account., i assume you when you said *"login accounts"* you are still talking about MysQL user accounts ? .. Even the manual says -> *'PASSWORD() is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications"*

Comment: *"Why do you want to "restore" passwords? That's not how passwords work"*  Indeed @NicoHaase now it really sounds like `PASSWORD()` is used on a unsafe way for application user accounts..  i could understand "restoring" the old MySQL user accounts passwords to the new MySQL server.

Comment: Yes. this is to be restore all old user accounts into new DB server. Now I got a solution to transfer existing records with manual code instead of `PASSWORD()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replaced this code part for `PASSWORD()` function and its working as expected.

```
SELECT CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('PWD')))))
```

Comment: Nice. One refinement: test for empty strings upstream of this, because the code above would turn "" (empty string) into "*BE1BDEC0AA74B4DCB079943E70528096CCA985F8", whereas the old PASSWORD function turns "" into "" (empty string in, empty string out).